# Importing Large Matrices: Import All or by Column? - MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, import

General programming question, but there might be specific considerations for Matlab.

I will be importing very large data file. Is it better practice/faster/more efficient to import the whole file onto the memory and then divide it into submatrices, or rather to just import every n columns into a new matrix?

My guess is that it would be faster to load it all into the cache and then deal with it, but it's just an uneducated guess.

Comment: What format is your data file in? Is it a text file, ASCII-delimited numeric file, CSV file? There are specialized handlers for several data types built in to MATLAB that use similar syntax to C in that you open a file stream, read from the file stream, and finally close the file stream. I think one of these would be your best bet.

Comment: Could you specify what you will do with the matrix? If the goal is just to load the matrix into memory and no computation afterwards, I can't see any reason to exploit the cache.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comment, Engineero. I am currently writing my code on the assumption that the data is a CSV. What I am doing is saying `data = csvread('filename')`   and then dividing the data matrix into several matrices. say: `matrix_1_2 = data(:,1:2)`, etc. Is that better than scanning for the first two columns only, saving them, then scanning for the second pair of columns, etc?

Comment: Da Kuang: There will be a lot of matrix manipulation and multiplication. I am guessing the most efficient way is to not even divide the large matrix, but use subsets of it in the calculations (for instance `resultingMatrix = data(:,1:n) .* data(:,n+1:2*n)`, but that will make the code less legible for others)

Comment: Write the code in the simplest and most readable way possible.  If the data comfortably fits in main memory, you'll be fine.  If it doesn't, you're in a world of hurt, and you'll need a better disk storage format (binary) and blocked algorithms that will operate on batches of the data.  You *certainly* don't want to parse each line of the CSV more than once, which blocking by column would do.

Comment: Great advice, thank you, @Peter! Didn't realize it would parse each line over and over again. Makes sense now that you mention. Lesson learned!

Comment: First, use textscan to import a .csv. Second, you might need to resort to block importing, i.e. blocks of rows (ratehr than columns). Also, in my experience I noticed that the [size of the block matters](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/75341-what-is-the-optimal-block-size-for-importing-a-big-csv-with-textscan) and the biggest is not the fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, the best approach is to parse it once, using either csvread (which uses dlmread which uses textscan - so the time penalty is not significant). This is of course given that a very big file is not larger than the amount of free RAM you have. 
If a very big file is larger than RAM (I just had to parse a 31GB file for example), than I would use fopen, read line by line (or chunks, blocks whatever you prefer) and write these a writable mat file. 
This way you can write huge files limited by your file system in theory.